# boost::asio::async_completion object declaration doesn't being compiled on VS 2019 with boost 1.81

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have minimized the piece of code which can't be compiled on windows VS 2019 with boost 1.81. But it works fine on linux (ubuntu 20.04). Main function is empty as I just want to make it compile.

```
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

void wait(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
        boost::asio::async_completion<boost::asio::yield_context, void(boost::system::error_code)> init(yield);
}

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support
> default-int   np-tests    C:\boost\boost_1_81_0\boost\asio\async_result.hpp   651
> Error C3646   'completion_handler_type': unknown override
> specifier np-tests    C:\boost\boost_1_81_0\boost\asio\async_result.hpp   651
> Error C2039   'completion_handler_type': is not a member of
> 'boost::asio::async_resultboost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor,void
> (boost::system::error_code)>' np-tests    C:\boost\boost_1_81_0\boost\asio\async_result.hpp   650

Does anyone have a clue why VS behaves like this and how to make it work?
Thx.

Comment: That code doesn't compile online (gcc 12 on Linux): https://godbolt.org/z/n7T6hzv51

Comment: Ok. Thx. I start thinking the real root cause is boost version.

Comment: I've marked this duplicate since it has the same cause as the other question, which already has an answer. Hope the answer there works for you, if not please ask.